# Getting an error in my function that returns values in an array using pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I am trying to learn arrays and pointers in C. I'm trying to write a program that in a function: gets 2 numbers from the user, puts them in an array, and returns them to the main function. I am getting an error and I don't understand what the problem is. Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void get_nums(float *x)
{
    float num1, num2;

    printf("enter two numbers: ");
    scanf("%f %f", &num1, &num2);

    *x[0] = num1;
    *x[1] = num2;

}

main(){

    float x[2];
    float (*p_x)[2] = &x;

    get_nums(p_x[2]);

    printf("Number 1: %f\nNumber 2: %f", x[0], x[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

I am getting an error on these 2 lines

```
    *x[0] = num1;
    *x[1] = num2;
```

The error message is

> Error: operand of '*' must be a pointer

I don't see what it is that is wrong. Does anyone see the problem?

EDIT: I changed the 2 lines to

```
    x[0] = num1;
    x[1] = num2;
```

and now I can run the program. However I get a new error after I enter the two numbers. The error message is:

> ```
>   Unhandled exception at 0x40e00000 in arraysandpointers.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation.
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the `*`. Just this is fine:

```
x[0] = num1;
x[1] = num2;
```

In your original code `x[0]` already is of type `float`. `*x[0]` will try to deference it - which is not possible since `x[0]` isn't a pointer. Therefore it doesn't compile.

EDIT : Also change your main to this:

```
int main(){

    float x[2];
    get_nums(x);

    printf("Number 1: %f\nNumber 2: %f", x[0], x[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

It is not necessary to have the `p_x`. And it is what's causing the crash.

Comment: That worked, however I am now getting a new error. After I enter the two numbers I get the error: "Unhandled exception at 0x40e00000 in arrayandpointers.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation."

Answer (score 2):

`*X` can be considered as an array of `X` like `X[]`. So when you are writing as `*X[0]` it considers as a 2D array. So remove the pointers in `X[0]` and `X[1]`.

Remove these two lines:

```
float (*p_x)[2] = &x;
get_nums(p_x[2]);
```

You can directly do `get_nums(x)`.